# instruction about dragon book TAC(three address code)

Tags: compiler-construction

im writting program which translate ast to tac,all of my related knowledge is from dragon book.but i have some doubt when im attempting to write code for array member reference and struct member reference.

in c language, essentially,x=arr[i] is equivalent to x = *(arr+i) which means base addr of arr plus offest.

however,in tac,there is also exist instruction such as x=*y and *x=y,so can we use latter replace former in practice?i want to know in dragon book,x=arr[i] or arr[i]=x is theoretical or for writting rather than in practice.for following tac:

before: x = arr[i];//dragon book used

after: t1 = arr+i;//calculate addr

x=*t1;// Load mem(t1) to x

finally,if it can,how to represent latter?do we need add Load/Store IR?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you will require `load`/`store` instructions in your intermediate representation.

The dragon book appears to introduce this array subscript notation to act as a kind of sugar for `load`/`store` operations in the IR. Consider Ex. 2.20 from the book:

```
a[i] = 2 * a[j-k]
```

becomes normalised to

```
t3 = j - k
t2 = a[t3]
t1 = 2 * t2
a[i] = t1
```

An understated point of the conversion into three-address code (or a similar IR), is that complex expressions become broken up; all intermediary computations are given names (such as the introduced temporaries in the example conversion above), and all operands are simple (they're either variables or constants). This is the more important aspect of the conversion to a TAC IR, because the atomic nature of operands to the `x[y] = z` and `z = x[y]` can more easily have corresponding `load`/`store` targets instructions selected for them.

The dragon book's choice of keeping the array subscript notation seems to be purely for consistency of presentation. Later on in the book (see Ex. 2.80), these IR instruction trees are tiled with corresponding `load`/`store` ("`LD`/`ST`") instructions.

A very simplistic instruction set, often shown in academia, is that of "Schizo-Jouette" ([https://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~robin/class/510/jouette.pdf](https://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/%7Erobin/class/510/jouette.pdf)). A more practical book than the dragon book for this stuff is Andrew Appel's "Modern Compiler Implementation in ML/Java/C", which shows the Schizo-Jouette tree matching scheme and explains to the reader how to perform instruction selection using maximal munch tree matching.

Comment: im appreciate for your answer,additionally,do you know how to represent label in tac?i find some related resource or code,they create label use string,but i use a pointer to point a target instruction and a linked list to represent instruction stream,i think string is not a elegant approach,is it correctly?@contificate